# union of fix points of $f\in\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)\setminus\{1\}$ is a proper subset of $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

> Let $F ⊆ K$ be finite fields. Show that $\operatorname{Stab}_{\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)}(z)=\{1\}$ for at least one $z\in K$.

**My attempt**
Firstly $z\notin F$, since any element of $F$ is fixed by $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$.

$\operatorname{Stab}_{\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)}(z)=\{1\}$ is equivalent to that $f(z)$ for all $f\in\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$ are distinct.

Existence of $z$ is equivalent to that $\bigcup_{f\in\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)\setminus\{1\}}\text{Fix}(f)$ is a proper subset of $K$.

---

I'm a beginner to Galois theory, could you help me proving this?

Comment: The answer below is great. This also follows from the weaker assertion that $F = \Bbb F_p(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$ (a "primitive element"). You can prove this in the case of finite fields by a nice counting argument using the fact that subfields of $F$ have order a power of $p$ and there is at most one subfield of each cardinality. (Suppose no element of $F$ generates $F$. Then every element of $F$ lies in a proper subfield...)

Comment: [Primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$K^\times$ is cyclic, let $a$ be a generator. If some $f \in \mathrm{Gal}(K/F)$ fixes $a$, then it fixes all of $K$. (Do you see why?) By Galois theory, this implies that $f=1$ is the identity.